# Angular 7 - Flickering images upon polling

Tags: angular, chat, flicker

I'm developing a chat platform. Currently I'm polling images from an API call. However, if I were to upload images on the chat platform, the images would start flicker periodically each time I'm calling the api to load all the messages. Is there a workaround to this?

If I were turn off the disable cache option in the google chrome network options, or if I were to use incognito mode, the flickering would not occur.

**chat.component.ts**

```
setupMessagePoll(chatId: string, period: number): Subscription {
    return interval(period).subscribe(() => {
      this.chatService.listChatMessages(id).subscribe(messages=> 
      this.messages = messages)
    });
 }

setImageAsBackground(message) {
    const a = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(
      'background-image: url("' +
        this.attachmentSrc(message) +
        '"); ' +
        'background-repeat: no-repeat; ' +
        'background-size: cover;' +
        'background-position: center;'
    );
   return a;
}


attachmentSrc(m: Message): string {
    if (m.attachmentId === this.placeholderUpload) {
      return ['assets', 'placeholder-uploading.png'].join('/');
    } else {
      return [
        environment.apiBasePath,
        'chat',
        m.chatId,
        'image',
        m.attachmentId,
      ].join('/');
    }
  }

trackByFn(index, message: Message) {  //newly added trackByFn function
    return message.id;
}
```

**chat.component.html**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let message of messages; last as isLast; trackBy: trackByFn">
   <div class="col-12 p-0 d-flex" [ngClass]="{ 'justify-content-end': message.authorId === self.id }">
    <!-- Profile image  -->
        <div
            class="message-attachment"
            *ngIf="message.attachmentId"
            [style]="setImageAsBackground(message)"
            (click)="setLightboxImage(attachmentSrc(message))"
          ></div>
</ng-container>
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: It is happening because on `messages` change, chat component rerenders. To avoid rerendering you should use `trackBy` function - https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5?gi=a4aa1c039748

Comment: hi, I added a trackBy function at the end of my ngFor loop, but the flickering still occurs when I open my developer tools. I added a trackByFn that returns a message.id (updated the code above) Appreciate if you could point out if I made a mistake!